# PHP string with commas empty?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, jquery-ui-selectable

I try to read a string from REQUEST_PHP, which is a string containing commas, separating the values of an array.  I save the index value of selected elements of a list to an array.  I join them and then use console.log and an alert box to confirm the values are there.  For instance say its a list of 8 items and numbers 1,2,4,6 are selected.  console.log displays (1,2,4,6) i use document.getElemenetById and set the value to value of join(array) and console.log shows the values are there correctly but when i go to submit the form and print php results on the subsequent page, or submit them to MySQL database the values for the selected item list is blank.  Other aspects of the form submit fine via php.  Have been messing with this for hours and tried numerous things any help would be appreciated.

Here's relevant code

Javascript:

```
var testies= "";
$(function() {
    $( "#Testing1" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
        var selectedNumbers = "";
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function(i) {
            if(i != 0) {
                selectedNumbers += ",";
             }
             selectedNumbers += $(this).index()+1;           
           });
           console.log(selectedNumbers);
            var poop = [selectedNumbers];
            testies = poop.join();
            console.log(testies);
            document.getElementById("placeholder").value = testies;
         }

    }); 
});

function showAlert() {
  alert(placeholder.value);
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>

<strong>&#149; Select Options? </strong> (select all that apply)
        <ol id="Testing1" class="multiclicklist">
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" class="checkbox" value="1">Opt 1</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="2">Opt 2</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="3">Opt 3</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="4">Opt 4</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="5">Opt 5</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="6">Opt 6</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="7">Opt 7</li>
            <li input type="checkbox" class="ui-state-default" name="testing2[]" value="8">Opt 8</li>
        </ol>

        <br>
        <input type="button" value="CheckValue" onclick="showAlert();">
```

PHP Code:

```
$active = trim($_REQUEST['placeholder']);
 print($active);
```

I'm a little frustrated so any help be very welcom

Comment: Your variable names are ridiculous

Comment: I do not see any `form`, or any ajax code, how exactly are you expecting the `placeholder` value to reach the server?

Comment: I am aware they are, it happens when you've tried a dozen different things and continue to not find an answer

Comment: You're building strings, stuffing those strings into single-element arrays, joining that array back to a string.. and wondering why your index numbers are all off? you're getting 1,2,3,4 because you built a **NEW** array which has no relationship whatsoever with the array of selected objects.

Comment: xForty the form code is on the page it works for other things that is not the issue it submits by <form name="surveyform"  action="scripts/surveyform.php" method="POST">

Comment: yea, change that div to:

`<input type="text" id="placeholder" name="placeholder" />` and try.

`name` attribute is important, because `id="placeholder"` means poop when you are sending data :p

Comment: Mark no thats not what i'm wondering at all.  I'm getting the correct index values for the selectable one. the only thing i'm not getting is my information over to PHP for the paticular placeholder div

Comment: because `<div>` is not exactly what you use inside `form` to send data.

Comment: xFortyFourx, I think you may be on to something there

Comment: do you have testies bound to onsubmit? Or do you manually click the button before submitting?

Comment: @user2048239 yes I am.

Comment: Didn't even see that it's a div, i second @xFortyFourx

Comment: xFortyFourx I appreciate your genius

Comment: @user2048239 so I guess that worked?

Comment: It did work, and yes everything is in a proper form bound to submit, the other button is just one i use to test elements.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

to

```
<input id="placeholder" name="placeholder" />
```

Assuming you have everything inside a proper `<form>`.

Comment: Thanks so much xFortyFourx